macOS 15.1 Update: External Monitor Flickering & System Lock
I'm using a MacBook Pro with an Apple M1 Pro chip, connected to an external LG Pro Gamer Ultrawide 29" monitor (model 29UM69G-B) via USB-C. After updating to macOS Sequoia 15.1 (build 24B83), the external monitor has started flickering and disconnecting intermittently.
When the MacBook lid is closed (displaying only on the external monitor), the flickering not only disrupts the display but also triggers system lock (similar to pressing ^⌘Q), interrupting app sessions and even disconnecting video calls, such as those on Microsoft Teams.
With the MacBook lid open, the issue persists, but the MacBook’s display remains stable, while the external monitor continues to flicker.
So far, I’ve tried setting the refresh rate to 60Hz and switching USB-C ports, but the issue remains.
Has anyone else experienced something similar since the 15.1 update? Any suggestions for fixes or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help!

Please boot in Safe Mode and see whether there's any difference. This is to rule out a third-party software conflict. Also, if the monitor is connected through a hub or dock, try connecting it directly. Disconnect all other peripherals.

I did it now and continues to blink... It connected directly in USB-C port... And it started after update to Sequoia 15.1... So, probably i have to wait for an update :-(

Maybe LG will update the firmware. Check for that. I don’t know of anything else you can do.

Issue of MacOS v15.1 from Beta days till now. Direct USB-C display are having issues. Check https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255821676

As mentioned in Ashish Sharma's comment, direct USB-C display connections are having flicking issues with Sequoia 15.1 (and possibly earlier versions).
According to this thread in the Apple Support Community, it is a known issue and Apple support has raised it to the development team.
